# How do I name rows

Tags: r, header, row, names

I have a data set hdata(as picture1 shows):

[image]

row names were automatically given by R
How do I name rows by y1 to y6 instead of `v1` to `v6` given by R?

Comment: Based on the image, the 'v1', to 'v6' are column names. `colnames(hdata) <- paste0('y', seq_along(hdata))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the column names with `paste`

```
colnames(hdata) <- paste0('y', seq_along(hdata))
```

Or use `sub`

```
colnames(hdata) <- sub('v', 'y', colnames(hdata))
```